Movie where a girl and a thief's bodies magically swapped with each other
I watched this movie in about 2003-04 on TV, so I do not know the release year. Here are some plot details I remember:
A girl who was the leading actress in the movie stole a pair earrings, but one of them gets lost. That lost piece was picked by a thief. That girl wears one earring and that thief also wears that one. When it happens, their bodies are swapped with each other except the mind. That girl and her friends try to find out that lost piece of earring. In the end, she finds it and wears, and the bodies are swapped again.
One of that girl's friends was blonde as far as I remember. It was a comedy movie. I have tried a lot, but couldn't find it. Hope you guys help me. Thanks.

You're describing the plot of The Hot Chick with Rob Schneider from 2002.

Jessica Spencer is the hottest, most popular girl in high school. Jessica, her best friend April, and a couple of other hot girls Lulu and Keecia visit the mall to hang out and do some shopping. They enter a new age store, where they check out a pair of ancient earrings. Unbeknownst to Jessica, these are magical ones set in ancient Abyssinia. A princess known as Princess Nawa is disgusted by the groom of her arranged marriage and switches bodies with a slave girl by means of an enchanted set of earrings. Since the earrings are not for sale, Jessica steals them. But the next morning she gets a big dose of reality when she wakes up in the body of a 30-something lowlife male, Clive, a career criminal. Clive finds himself in Jessica's body. Now it's up to Jessica (in Clive's body) to find a way to get her body back, while Clive (in Jessica's body) takes advantage of his new body to set in motion a crime spree to put the blame on Jessica!

It also starred Rachel McAdams and Anna Faris. Here's the trailer:




Yes that's the one. Thanks.
